# ResourceManager.GetString fails in unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, resources

I've created an assembly MyResources with two resx:

- MyResources.resx
- MyResources.en.resx

Inside the assembly I've added a handler-class containing a GetString-wrapper inside a ResHandler-class:

```
    public string GetResString(string key)
    {            
        return _manager.GetString(key, _culture);
    }
```

_culture is simply a property which can be set from outside:

```
    public void ChangeCulture(CultureInfo newCulture)
    {            
        _culture = newCulture;
    }
```

If I call this code from a lets say console-app, everything works fine:

```
    var res = ResHandler.GetInstance(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    //change the culture to "en"
    res.ChangeCulture(new CultureInfo("en"));
    Console.WriteLine(res.GetResString("TXT_0001"));
```

This code writes the english version to the console. However, if I call the exact same code from a unit-test-method, the contents of the MyResources.resx will appear. Whats wrong here? Are unit-tests unable to do this for some reason?

Comment: No. I mean it always falls back to the CurrentThread-Culture in unit-test-mode. What do you mean with 'disappear' :-)?

Comment: You said that "content of the MyResources.resx will appear" but what is expected? BTW, how ResHandler.ChangeCUlture() is implemented, where is it set culture passed as parameter?

Comment: Ok, i edited the post. With "appear" I ment to say, that the correkt string out of the resource is written to the console. Sorry, sometimes I'm translating wrong from german to english ;-).

Comment: Have you tried to set a break point around all places where value is assigned to _culture? Also set a breakpoint on the line _manager.GetString(key, _culture); and see perhaps null value is passed so in this case this could cause some kind of default or unexpected behaviour

Comment: Yes, I already have done this. The assignment inside of ChangeUICulture is made correctly. No error appears at all. Remember: If called from Console-App, everything works correctly without any code-change!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware that satellite assemblies are stored in a subdirectory of the directory that contains the EXE.  Like "en-US" or "en" for English.  Problem is, your test runs under a different EXE, mstest.exe and not your app.exe.  It will therefore not find the satellite assembly.  I think you can fix this by using Deployment in the test settings, not sure.

Comment: I guess, this is the right way. Thanks for that, but if I configure to deploy the "en"-folder there, it won't be copied to the TestResults\*\out-Folder. Any ideas what is needed else?