# Use satellite assemblies from another dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, satellite-assembly

I have a dll which contains some resx files as EmbeddedResources for the localization.
That dll is used mostly for the creation of ASP.NET websites and it's worked fine.

But when I use the dll in my test project (basically that's just another dll), I can't have access to the satellite assemblies content, for example I can't access to the English translation of my messages. It return only the fallback messages.

Code used :

```
ResourceManager _resourceManager = new ResourceManager(baseName, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
_resourceManager.GetString(key, cultureInfo);
```

baseName is the fully qualified name of the resource, for example: myNamespace.MyResourceName.

I'm thinking that it's the loading of the dll which is different when the project is a dll or a website, but I don't know how to load it correctly.

Anyone have an idea or a tip?

Thanks.

Edit:
I have the dll A with some resx:

- Messages.resx
- Messages.en.resx
- Messages.de.resx
- etc...

At the end of the build, it generates some dlls:

- A.dll
- en/A.resources.dll
- de/A.resources.dll
- etc...

If the dll A is referenced by a website, the website can have access to the localized resource, like a message in en or de.
But if it's another dll like my unit tests dll which references the dll A, it's always the fallback messages which are returned.

Comment: It's the full qualified name of the resource, like MyNamespace.MyResourceName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem coming from the use of the ResourceManager in the unit test, the languages folder aren't copied in the base folder used by the unit tests, see this question: [ResourceManager.GetString fails in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056614/resourcemanager-getstring-fails-in-unit-tests).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are loading the resources for the executing assembly, not the satellite assembly.  Try:

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load("my.other.namespace");
var manager =  new ResourceManager(assembly.GetType().Name + ".Localisation", assembly);

var str = manager(key, cultureInfo);
```

replacing `my.other.namespace` to the full namespace of the satellite assembly.

Comment: The executing assembly contains all the resx files and is the root of the satellite assemblies.
At the end of the build, I have that:
-MainAssembly.dll
-en/MainAssembly.resources.dll
-etc...

Comment: Could you make your question more clear?  I read this as DLL **A** references satellite DLL **B** and code in **A** needs to access the resources of **B**.

Comment: It's exactly that, except that B have auto-generated satellite assemblies with localized content. And I can't access to the localized content.

Comment: Ok, well hopefully my code, when placed in **A**, should solve the issue.  I believe the problem is that `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` will be giving you **A**, whereas my code will get you **B**.  Of course, I could be wrong :)

Comment: I can assure you that the loaded dll is the good one, with the basic/fallback messages, but it doesn't load the satellite assemblies with the other localization messages. I have verified that with my current loading method and with your answer.

Comment: It appears that I wrong since the beginning, the problem coming from the unit tests: the languages folder with A.resources.dll aren't copied in the Out folder used by the unit tests, so the resources aren't loaded but the ResourceManager. But thanks for your time and your answer.